# Seasonal weather data

Tags: time-series

I have some twenty years of weather data with daily average temperature. I would like to make a histogram with aggregated monthly average for the whole period. I tried to do something like this https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/time-series-processing/trends-and-seasonalities.html?product=language
But it didn’t work since my weights in WeightedData can be positive and negative. My data looks like this: 
[image]

```
data = {{"1965-12-01",0.5},{"1965-12-02",-4.1},{"1965-12-03",-0.8},{"1965-12-04",2.},{"1965-12-05",1.3},{"1965-12-06",0.4},{"1965-12-07",-6.6},{"1965-12-08",-3.9},{"1965-12-09",0.3},{"1965-12-10",1.2},{"1965-12-11",-3.},{"1965-12-12",-9.4},{"1965-12-13",-13.},{"1965-12-14",-10.5},{"1965-12-15",-4.6},{"1965-12-16",-6.5},{"1965-12-17",-8.},{"1965-12-18",-2.2},{"1965-12-19",1.7},{"1965-12-20",2.1},{"1965-12-21",-4.6},{"1965-12-22",-2.8},{"1965-12-23",-0.2},{"1965-12-24",-0.1},{"1965-12-25",0.9},{"1965-12-26",0.5},{"1965-12-27",-0.8},{"1965-12-28",-6.5},{"1965-12-29",-5.6},{"1965-12-30",-5.2},{"1965-12-31",-6.9},{"1966-01-01",-8.},{"1966-01-02",-4.2},{"1966-01-03",-7.3},{"1966-01-04",-12.9},{"1966-01-05",-12.},{"1966-01-06",-1.8},{"1966-01-07",-0.1},{"1966-01-08",-3.4},{"1966-01-09",-3.8},{"1966-01-10",-3.},{"1966-01-11",-3.8},{"1966-01-12",-5.3},{"1966-01-13",-5.9},{"1966-01-14",-7.9},{"1966-01-15",-6.2},{"1966-01-16",-8.},{"1966-01-17",-7.5},{"1966-01-18",-4.4},{"1966-01-19",-13.3},{"1966-01-20",-8.2},{"1966-01-21",-6.1},{"1966-01-22",-3.9},{"1966-01-23",-5.6},{"1966-01-24",-8.3},{"1966-01-25",-4.2},{"1966-01-26",-5.2},{"1966-01-27",-3.5},{"1966-01-28",-6.7},{"1966-01-29",-4.1},{"1966-01-30",1.3},{"1966-01-31",2.2},{"1966-02-01",-5.4},{"1966-02-02",-13.9},{"1966-02-03",-11.8},{"1966-02-04",-13.7},{"1966-02-05",-7.4},{"1966-02-06",-9.5},{"1966-02-07",-15.3},{"1966-02-08",-24.4},{"1966-02-09",-23.},{"1966-02-10",-12.8},{"1966-02-11",-19.2},{"1966-02-12",-20.2},{"1966-02-13",-18.1},{"1966-02-14",-11.1},{"1966-02-15",-13.},{"1966-02-16",-14.6},{"1966-02-17",-16.5},{"1966-02-18",-15.5},{"1966-02-19",-17.5},{"1966-02-20",-7.4},{"1966-02-21",0.6},{"1966-02-22",-0.7},{"1966-02-23",-1.1},{"1966-02-24",1.5},{"1966-02-25",0.2},{"1966-02-26",0.4},{"1966-02-27",1.4},{"1966-02-28",1.6},{"1966-03-01",-0.4},{"1966-03-02",-0.5},{"1966-03-03",2.9},{"1966-03-04",1.9},{"1966-03-05",1.1},{"1966-03-06",1.3},{"1966-03-07",2.1},{"1966-03-08",2.8},{"1966-03-09",0.7},{"1966-03-10",-0.2},{"1966-03-11",-0.5},{"1966-03-12",-6.4},{"1966-03-13",-8.2},{"1966-03-14",-7.8},{"1966-03-15",-5.6},{"1966-03-16",0.7},{"1966-03-17",4.},{"1966-03-18",0.4},{"1966-03-19",-1.8},{"1966-03-20",2.6},{"1966-03-21",3.1},{"1966-03-22",1.8},{"1966-03-23",2.},{"1966-03-24",0.3},{"1966-03-25",-3.1},{"1966-03-26",-4.9},{"1966-03-27",-1.5},{"1966-03-28",0.6},{"1966-03-29",0.6},{"1966-03-30",-0.2},{"1966-03-31",0.4},{"1966-04-01",0.9},{"1966-04-02",0.8},{"1966-04-03",4.},{"1966-04-04",2.2},{"1966-04-05",0.8},{"1966-04-06",1.8},{"1966-04-07",2.3},{"1966-04-08",2.2},{"1966-04-09",1.3},{"1966-04-10",-1.3},{"1966-04-11",-3.6},{"1966-04-12",-4.5},{"1966-04-13",-4.6},{"1966-04-14",-4.4},{"1966-04-15",-3.6},{"1966-04-16",-4.5},{"1966-04-17",-3.5},{"1966-04-18",-2.5},{"1966-04-19",0.},{"1966-04-20",0.4},{"1966-04-21",3.3},{"1966-04-22",1.7},{"1966-04-23",1.4},{"1966-04-24",3.8},{"1966-04-25",4.6},{"1966-04-26",4.9},{"1966-04-27",3.1},{"1966-04-28",6.7},{"1966-04-29",7.9},{"1966-04-30",8.5},{"1966-05-01",8.7},{"1966-05-02",8.9},{"1966-05-03",9.5},{"1966-05-04",6.7},{"1966-05-05",4.5},{"1966-05-06",1.7},{"1966-05-07",4.1},{"1966-05-08",6.7},{"1966-05-09",5.9},{"1966-05-10",8.},{"1966-05-11",8.},{"1966-05-12",6.1},{"1966-05-13",6.8},{"1966-05-14",9.4},{"1966-05-15",10.7},{"1966-05-16",9.5},{"1966-05-17",10.7},{"1966-05-18",13.3},{"1966-05-19",10.5},{"1966-05-20",8.3},{"1966-05-21",8.3},{"1966-05-22",8.8},{"1966-05-23",9.},{"1966-05-24",8.9},{"1966-05-25",8.9},{"1966-05-26",8.},{"1966-05-27",9.4},{"1966-05-28",10.7},{"1966-05-29",10.},{"1966-05-30",11.9},{"1966-05-31",12.},{"1966-06-01",10.9},{"1966-06-02",13.},{"1966-06-03",9.5},{"1966-06-04",10.2},{"1966-06-05",12.3},{"1966-06-06",12.8},{"1966-06-07",10.8},{"1966-06-08",11.5},{"1966-06-09",14.3},{"1966-06-10",15.6},{"1966-06-11",17.4},{"1966-06-12",18.3},{"1966-06-13",18.9},{"1966-06-14",18.7},{"1966-06-15",19.1},{"1966-06-16",19.7},{"1966-06-17",21.4},{"1966-06-18",21.5},{"1966-06-19",21.5},{"1966-06-20",19.1},{"1966-06-21",16.7},{"1966-06-22",15.7},{"1966-06-23",17.1},{"1966-06-24",17.2},{"1966-06-25",15.1},{"1966-06-26",15.1},{"1966-06-27",14.7},{"1966-06-28",13.9},{"1966-06-29",18.7},{"1966-06-30",16.5},{"1966-07-01",17.1},{"1966-07-02",17.1},{"1966-07-03",15.2},{"1966-07-04",16.3},{"1966-07-05",15.},{"1966-07-06",16.4},{"1966-07-07",14.2},{"1966-07-08",15.3},{"1966-07-09",17.5},{"1966-07-10",16.5},{"1966-07-11",15.2},{"1966-07-12",15.6},{"1966-07-13",15.2},{"1966-07-14",14.2},{"1966-07-15",13.8},{"1966-07-16",15.3},{"1966-07-17",15.1},{"1966-07-18",17.3},{"1966-07-19",18.8},{"1966-07-20",20.2},{"1966-07-21",21.},{"1966-07-22",22.3},{"1966-07-23",18.9},{"1966-07-24",17.4},{"1966-07-25",17.2},{"1966-07-26",14.6},{"1966-07-27",15.6},{"1966-07-28",15.8},{"1966-07-29",15.4},{"1966-07-30",14.},{"1966-07-31",14.2},{"1966-08-01",14.7},{"1966-08-02",13.7},{"1966-08-03",14.7},{"1966-08-04",13.1},{"1966-08-05",15.},{"1966-08-06",14.2},{"1966-08-07",15.9},{"1966-08-08",15.2},{"1966-08-09",15.7},{"1966-08-10",15.5},{"1966-08-11",15.1},{"1966-08-12",14.9},{"1966-08-13",14.1},{"1966-08-14",15.1},{"1966-08-15",13.9},{"1966-08-16",13.4},{"1966-08-17",15.6},{"1966-08-18",16.},{"1966-08-19",16.1},{"1966-08-20",15.},{"1966-08-21",14.4},{"1966-08-22",13.8},{"1966-08-23",14.4},{"1966-08-24",13.6},{"1966-08-25",14.8},{"1966-08-26",13.},{"1966-08-27",13.5},{"1966-08-28",15.2},{"1966-08-29",15.5},{"1966-08-30",13.8},{"1966-08-31",14.6},{"1966-09-01",14.4},{"1966-09-02",14.1},{"1966-09-03",14.7},{"1966-09-04",14.8},{"1966-09-05",15.6},{"1966-09-06",14.3},{"1966-09-07",15.3},{"1966-09-08",13.6},{"1966-09-09",8.7},{"1966-09-10",10.8},{"1966-09-11",13.6},{"1966-09-12",12.6},{"1966-09-13",14.1},{"1966-09-14",13.5},{"1966-09-15",13.},{"1966-09-16",10.2},{"1966-09-17",12.3},{"1966-09-18",7.8},{"1966-09-19",10.9},{"1966-09-20",14.7},{"1966-09-21",12.2},{"1966-09-22",9.4},{"1966-09-23",9.1},{"1966-09-24",12.5},{"1966-09-25",7.1},{"1966-09-26",10.5},{"1966-09-27",5.3},{"1966-09-28",3.5},{"1966-09-29",7.1},{"1966-09-30",10.5},{"1966-10-01",9.3},{"1966-10-02",11.4},{"1966-10-03",11.6},{"1966-10-04",11.1},{"1966-10-05",4.6},{"1966-10-06",7.5},{"1966-10-07",9.6},{"1966-10-08",11.4},{"1966-10-09",9.1},{"1966-10-10",6.5},{"1966-10-11",7.4},{"1966-10-12",6.},{"1966-10-13",6.1},{"1966-10-14",6.3},{"1966-10-15",8.7},{"1966-10-16",10.5},{"1966-10-17",11.2},{"1966-10-18",10.},{"1966-10-19",9.3},{"1966-10-20",9.6},{"1966-10-21",9.8},{"1966-10-22",9.6},{"1966-10-23",8.8},{"1966-10-24",7.4},{"1966-10-25",1.8},{"1966-10-26",3.4},{"1966-10-27",4.6},{"1966-10-28",0.5},{"1966-10-29",-1.4},{"1966-10-30",2.6},{"1966-10-31",6.5},{"1966-11-01",4.5},{"1966-11-02",3.1},{"1966-11-03",2.8},{"1966-11-04",4.},{"1966-11-05",7.},{"1966-11-06",6.7},{"1966-11-07",6.1},{"1966-11-08",7.6},{"1966-11-09",7.6},{"1966-11-10",3.6},{"1966-11-11",-0.5},{"1966-11-12",1.},{"1966-11-13",4.3},{"1966-11-14",6.4},{"1966-11-15",4.5},{"1966-11-16",3.6},{"1966-11-17",3.1},{"1966-11-18",2.2},{"1966-11-19",0.},{"1966-11-20",0.9},{"1966-11-21",3.1},{"1966-11-22",1.4},{"1966-11-23",1.5},{"1966-11-24",2.8},{"1966-11-25",2.8},{"1966-11-26",3.6},{"1966-11-27",5.},{"1966-11-28",5.4},{"1966-11-29",1.4},{"1966-11-30",1.7}};
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is this unique data or can they be repeated using `AirTemperatureData[]`?

Comment: The data comes from an external source.

Comment: Maybe use the temperature in Kelvin?

Comment: Hi @supernasse, welcome to the mathematica Stack Exchange. Please consider adding a sample of your data to your question as copy-pasteable text so that we can help you easier. In the meantime, try to create a `TimeSeries` of your data and use `TimeSeriesAggregate`.

Comment: @supernasse What are the coordinates of the place for which data is obtained? Post sample data for 1 year.

Comment: The data comes from a region in Sweden called Värmlandsnäs. The source of the data is SMHI (Swedish Meteorological and Hydrological Institute), Latitud: 58.935039 | Longitud: 13.188071

Comment: @supernasse I've significantly modified my answer, please take a look!

Comment: @CarlLange Thats really great, exact what i was looking for, I could never have done it without you, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We need to manually group the data by month and take its mean, like so:

```
BarChart[GroupBy[data, DateValue[First@#, "MonthNameShort"] &, 
  Extract[{All, 2}] /* Mean], ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

To break this down: First, we `GroupBy` the month (`DateValue[First@#, "MonthNameShort"]`). Then we extract the second part of every value: `Extract[{All, 2}]` and then take the `Mean`.

[image]

We can now extend this to do it over weekdays for example:

```
BarChart[GroupBy[data, DateValue[First@#, "DayNameShort"] &, 
  Extract[{All, 2}] /* Mean], ChartLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

or any other period really:

[image]

Check the documentation for [`DateValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateValue.html) for the various different groupings. It's perhaps more useful if your data is higher resolution (for instance, down to the hour) but in any case, this is a nice, extensible solution.

Finally, you can modify what function you want to reduce your data by. You initially asked for Mean, but we could do other interesting things like the standard deviation, just by modifying the reduction function:

[image]